# Simple Ping EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ping

I am using `SimplePing.h` and `SimplePing.m` file from  Github:
https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Pinger/blob/master/iOS/Classes/SimplePing.m

It is crashing while pinging local IP address.

[image]

How can I stop crashing application, I added try catch block also, but it like `self->_scoket` is already de-allocated, is there any way to stop 
 or handle this crash??

Comment: this is a question you should submit issue request on that Github repo

Comment: @QuangVĩnhHà , thanks for your response, i already did ,but no reply , if someone have faced same issue , please help me.......on this.
Not only solving this issue , i want to check if we can bypass these types of crash or not